# Chaim Benveniste's involvement with Shabsai Tzvi, in Artscroll's "The Early Acharonim"

Tags: shabbetai-tzvi

Can someone who has that Artscroll book tell me what if anything it says on Rabbi Benveniste's following of Shabsai Tzvi before he did teshuvah for it?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

Please read for yourself from this linked image:

[image: The Early Acharonim Rabbi Chaim Beneviste]

Comment: I'm not sure this is legal

Comment: @robev it also occurred to me when I first looked at this question. I looked over what the copywriter office says prior to posting this photo concerning usage without seeking permission from the publisher. This is a very small percentage of the total work (almost 300 pages), is clearly only educational and is not being done for profit or benefit in any way. According to the guidelines of the US Government Patent Office, it should not be a problem.

Comment: It is for the profit and benefit of stackexchange inc who sells ads on this page

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you compensated by StackExchange? I remember monicacellio and others among the higher ups saying they were compensated rarely with some kind of occasional gift bag. But for most of us, myself included, our time and effort is only out of love for our brethren and our fellow man, Jew and non-Jew, who are connected with this site. No compensation is ever received or expected.

Comment: I am not compensated at all by stack exchange. All elected diamond moderators are volunteers.

Comment: @DoubleAA A personal, big relief. From your previous comment, I was concerned that you were suggesting somehow the actual current participants in this endeavor (at least some of them) may be receiving compensation of some kind via StackExchange for their moderation and/or answers. B”H!

Answer (score 3):

On page 182:

> During the period of messianic fervor surrounding Shabsai Tzvi (5425-27/1665-67), R' Chaim became an adherent of the movement, but subsequently repented of his attachment to the false Messiah when the latter became a Muslim.